# how to extract a specific list from a Model with Agile Toolkit

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

i'm working with Agile Toolkit

i got a Model_Product

```
class Model_Product extends Model_Table {
public $table="product";
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('name')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('price')->mandatory(true)->type('money');
    $this->addField('user_id')->refModel('Model_User')
        ->defaultValue($this->api->auth->get('id'));    
    //$this->hasOne('User',null,'email'); => send me an error message
}
}
```

and Model_User

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $table="user";

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('first_name')->mandatory('Prénom nécesssaire');
    $this->addField('last_name')->mandatory('Nom nécesssaire');
    $this->addField('email')->mandatory('entrez un email valide');
    $this->addField('nationality')->mandatory('nécessaire')->enum(array('FR','EN','US'));
    $this->addField('birthday')->defaultValue(date('Y-m-d'))->type('date');
    $this->addField('is_admin')->type('boolean');       
    $this->hasMany('Product','user_id');
}
```

I want to list on a User page all the products from one User

```
$q=$this->api->db->dsql();
$q->table('product')->where('product.user_id',$this->api->auth->model['id']);
$tab->add('GRID')->setModel($q);
```

Some way, I get it wrong because I get an error no mater how I try to filter my Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using newest ATK4 version from Github then you should grab it and stay up-to-date.

---

You should do like this:

1) In Model_Product create hasOne reference and not refModel (it's deprecated).

```
// adding 'user_id' parameter is not needed, it'll be calculated anyway
// but many developers add it anyway to clear thing up a bit.
$this->hasOne('User','user_id')->defaultValue($this->api->auth->get('id'));
```

2) Model_User is OK.
Just some side-notes about it:

- I don't think you should make birthday = today() by default.
  It's quite unbelievable that child at his first day in this world will use computer :)
- is_admin should be mandatory + defaultValue(false) - by default user is not admin.

3) How to list all all products from current user.

```
// model of current user
$model = $this->add('Model_User')
              ->load($this->api->auth->get('id'));
// add grid
$page->add('Grid')
     // reference Product model with condition already set
     ->setModel($model->ref('Product'));
```

and that's it.

---

Maybe even better and safer way is to define new model class for logged in user:

```
class Model_Myself extends Model_User {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addCondition('id', $this->api->auth->get('id'));
        $this->loadAny(); // I'm not sure do we have to explicitly load it here
    }
}
```

and then create grid like this

```
// model of products of current user
$prod_model = $this->add('Model_Myself')->ref('Product');
// add grid
$page->add('Grid')->setModel($prod_model);
```

Comment: But "It's quite unbelievable that child at his first day in this world will use computer :)" => I do expect my website to be so awesome baby will come anyway.

Comment: That would be a miracle :)))